# Understanding Haskell function in a lambda calculus way

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Im trying to define the filter function. Based on the function's definition, the filter' function is a function (say help function to differ from the main filter' function) that takes in a function and a list to give a list. The help function takes in a variable and gives back a Bool value. But according the line 4, the help function evaluates a along with [x] to give a Bool Value which then finally gives back a list.

So can I understand the help function as a function that takes in a and [a] to give a Bool value. The main filter' function then takes in this Bool value to give back a list?

Im aware that the function's definition does not suggest this but it's kinda logical based on the code. Thanks

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ [] = []
filter' a (x:xs)
  | a x == True = x:filter' a xs
  | otherwise = filter' a xs
```

Comment: What helper are you talking about? `filter'` *is* `filter`. This is just a straightforward recursive function, with `filter'` calling itself on the tail of its list input.

Comment: @chepner I think helper is the function given to `filter`. `filter'` is used to distinguish it from the real `filter`.

Comment: I don't see why you used "lambda calculus" here.

Comment: @MarkNeu He talks about the helper function evaluating `a`, which is the predicate passed to `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be clearer if we give the function of type `a -> Bool` a name other than `a`.

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ [] = []
filter' f (x:xs)
  | f x == True = x:filter' f xs
  | otherwise = filter' f xs
```

Now `f` has type `a -> Bool`, `x :: a`, and `xs :: [a]`.

I like your description of `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` as "takes in a function and a list to give a list".  The recursive calls to `filter'` in lines 4 & 5 have the same type.  `f` is passed along unchanged.  `xs` is a list of `a`s, but it's one `a` shorter than the input list.  There is only *one* function `filter'`.  The definition of the function refers to itself - that's an essential part of what we mean by "recursive function".

Comment: Why does f doesnt have the type a -> [a] -> Bool because it would make more sense to evaluate the predicate a on list [a]. Its illogical that a on itself can be determined as True or False, isnt it? The filter' function also takes in a list (second parameter) to give back a list. Is the first [a] in the type denotation xs and the second [a] represents x:filter' f xs. Thanks a lot. I find your explanation most comprehensible.

Comment: In every Haskell function type signature, the part after the last arrow is the result of the function.  Here, the second `[a]` is the result - the list of elements for which the predicate is True.  This `filter'` is the same as `filter` in the standard library.  It works for predicates on single elements.  For example, `filter even` or `filter (not . null)`.  This is also efficient - the function considers each `a` exactly once.

Comment: I think you have missed my point. i understand that the second [a] is the result                                                        filter' f (x:xs)
  | f x == True = x:filter' f xs                                                                                           What i dont get is the fourth line, we already have the function f and x as a in (a-> Bool) but im not sure where the first [a] is implemented.

Comment: The second argument to `filter` has the type `[a]`.  This list matches either `[]` or `(x:xs)`.  The line `filter _ [] = []` defines what to do if passed the empty list.  The 3 lines beginning `filter f (x:xs)` defines what to do if passed a non-empty list, and bind the two variables `x` and `xs`.  These two cases cover all possible lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax even more to aid your understanding:

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p [] = []
filter' p (x:xs)
     | (p  x) == True   = x : ( filter' p xs )
     | otherwise        =     ( filter' p xs )
```

Which is

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p [] = []
filter' p (x:xs)
     | (p  x)     = x : ( filter' p xs )
     | otherwise  =     ( filter' p xs )
```

Or translate it to the more basic constructs,

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) 
          ->   [a] -> [a]
filter' p = ( \ xs -> case xs of 
             {  []            ->  []
             ;  (x:ys) | p x  ->  x : ( filter' p ys )
             ;  (x:ys)        ->      ( filter' p ys )  } )
```

*" `p`"* is for *"predicate"*. It is used by `filter'` to test each `x` in the input `xs`, to decide whether to include that `x` or not in the output, according to the `Bool`ean value that the testing has produced.

`p` is just passed around unchanged from one invocation of `filter'` to the next. This is usually coded away with the so called "worker-wrapper" transformation,

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p xs = go xs where
   go [] = []
   go (x:xs) | p x   = x : go xs
             | otherwise = go xs
```

Lastly, a simpler-looking definition could also be

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p xs = go xs where
   go []     = []
   go (x:xs) = [x | p x] ++ go xs
```

which corresponds nicely with the `foldMap`-based definition

```
filter' p = foldMap (\ x -> [x | p x])
```